# Twitter API (Tweepy) how to get exact terms

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

So I'm trying to search for tweets containing particular words in the Twitter API (tweepy wrapper). However, when searching for words, I'm getting close-to results. (i.e Search for "there" but tweepy returns "there's". Is there any way to specify with tweepy, the exact term that you want.

Part of my code:

```
otherTweet = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=word and hashtag, count=1, lang="en").items(1) # searches for words needed to retweet later
    for a in otherTweet:
        ref = a.text.encode("unicode-escape")
        if "#" in ref and word not in ref.split(" ") or not otherTweet:
            otherTweet = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=word, count=1, lang="en").items(1) # Can't find tweet with right hashtag. 
            print "got here"
```

word and hashtag are both variables, word = "hello" hashtag = "#blessed" for example. I'm assuming I do something to them to receive specific terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to search for specific terms only, and remove any others you need to add whitespace around your search terms. Search for "there " or " there " instead of "there".

There's more complex routes, as in doing a secondary check for characters before and after, but this was the quickest and most useful route that I found in my application.

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to affect anything. Still getting things like "there!" might have to try second option.

Comment: I never worried about punctuation, and I assume that's the problem (twitter word search api may consider punctuation as whitespace for searches). If that's the case the second option is your best bet, but should be too difficult to implement. `.split()` is what you're looking for, and should only take one extra logic block to fix.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it seems that punctuation wasn't considered. Splitting is  what I had to do in the end. Bit annoying, but better than nothing.